# Creating a new data frame with different dimensions than original

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to get this desired output. So I have a data frame like the one below, where there are two columns with a list of numbers and an identifier. The list of numbers is stored as a character though. Basically I just need to have one row for each number in the list with the proper identifier. I tried using apply, and for each row I was able to create the list of numbers and equal-length list of the identifier, but what apply returns is a list of lists containing the two lists, which I didn't know how to easily convert to a dataframe. Any help would be appreciated.

```
df = data.frame(type = "1", y = 'set(1,2,3,4)')
desired_df = data.frame(type = rep("1", len(list(1,2,3,4)), y = c(1,2,3,4))
```

Comment: Hi rangerfan2430, there is an error in your code, did you mean : `desired_df = data.frame(type = rep("1", length(list(1,2,3,4))), y = c(1,2,3,4) )` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the data as shared, you can remove the unnecessary characters from `y` column using `gsub` and then use `separate_rows` to get data in long format.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(y = gsub('[set()]', '', y)) %>%
  tidyr::separate_rows(y, sep = ',', convert = TRUE)

#  type y
#1    1 1
#2    1 2
#3    1 3
#4    1 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible ways to handle it after you reformat the 'set(...)' into a list or a vector :

1) Straight from vector

```r
data.frame(type = "1", y = 1:4)
```

2) Create data frame from list then pivot longer

```r
tidyr::pivot_longer( data.frame(type = "1", y = list(1, 2, 3, 4)),
                     cols = -type
)
```

3) Then add a length (or nrow) variable